# How do I improve the speed of these PHP MySQLi queries without indexing?

Tags: php, mysqli

Lets start by saying that I cant use INDEXING as I need the INSERT, DELETE and UPDATE for this table to be super fast, which they are.

I have a page that displays a summary of order units collected in a database table.  To populate the table an order number is created and then individual units associated with that order are scanned into the table to recored which units are associated with each order.

For the purposes of this example the table has the following columns.

id, UID, order, originator, receiver, datetime

The individual unit quantities can be in the 1000's per order and the entire table is growing to hundreds of thousands of units.

The summary page displays the number of units per order and the first and last unit number for each order.  I limit the number of orders to be displayed to the last 30 order numbers.

For example:

Order 10 has 200 units.  first UID 1510 last UID 1756

Order 11 has 300 units.  first UID 1922 last UID 2831

..........

..........

Currently the response time for the query is about 3 seconds as the code performs the following:

1. Look up the last 30 orders by by id and sort by order number
2. While looking at each order number in the array

-- Count the number of database rows that have that order number

-- Select the first UID from all the rows as first

-- Select the last UID from all the rows as last

3. Display the result

I've determined the majority of the time is taken by the Count of the number of units in each order ~1.8 seconds and then determining the first and last numbers in each order ~1 second.

I am really interested in if there is a way to speed up these queries without INDEXING.  Here is the code with the queries.

First request selects the last 30 orders processed selected by id and grouped by order number.  This gives the last 30 unique order numbers.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT order, ANY_VALUE(receiver) AS receiver, ANY_VALUE(originator) AS originator, ANY_VALUE(id) AS id 
FROM scandb
GROUP BY order 
ORDER BY id 
DESC LIMIT 30");
```

While fetching the last 30 order numbers count the number of units and the first and last UID for each order.

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

    $count = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT order, COUNT(*) as count FROM scandb WHERE order ='".$row['order']."' "));

    $firstLast = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT (SELECT UID FROM scandb WHERE orderNumber ='".$row['order']."' ORDER BY UID LIMIT 1) as 'first', (SELECT UID FROM barcode WHERE order ='".$row['order']."' ORDER BY UID DESC LIMIT 1) as 'last'"));

echo "<td align= center>".$count['count']."</td>";
echo "<td align= center>".$firstLast['first']."</td>";
echo "<td align= center>".$firstLast['last']."</td>";

}
```

With 100K lines in the database this whole query is taking about 3 seconds. The majority of the time is in the $count and $firstlast queries.  I'd like to know if there is a more efficient way to get this same data in a faster time without Indexing the table.  Any special tricks that anyone has would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is the whole point of indexing. If you can't index the column you're looking up, the query has to scan the entire table and this takes time.

Comment: Seriously, why being so stubborn about not using indexes?  100K of rows in a table is not THAT BIG.  It should not slow down that much, all DBMS are optimized for such usage, it is a common needs.  I would kindly suggest you to put index on and check if it has a real impact.  I highly doubt the indexes would kill your processing with such volume.

Comment: @MichaelMuryn, Thanks for your reply.  It's 100K rows in the past few months, this is going to grow to millions of rows over the next year or two.   As the scanning input is being done in multiple locations with lots of simultaneous input scans the Indexing is certainly going to slow down the input which will affect a large majority of the users. The dashboard only gets used occasionally it is less important if its slow. I was hoping that someone smarter than me might have better query methods or advice that would give some improvement.

Comment: Even with millions of you, what are your fear?  It is not THAT BIG once again.  DBMS such are MySQL can handle this easily... Maybe you are just creating fear and think about premature optimization or I am missing something... I would enable indexes and evaluate from that.  Have you already noticed a significant decline in performance with indexes? (which I doubt at first glance)

Answer (score 1):

**Design your database with caution**

This first tip may seems obvious, but the fact is that most database problems come from badly-designed table structure.
For example, I have seen people storing information such as client info and payment info in the same database column. For both the database system and developers who will have to work on it, this is not a good thing.
When creating a database, always put information on various tables, use clear naming standards and make use of primary keys.

**Know what you should optimize**

If you want to optimize a specific query, it is extremely useful to be able to get an in-depth look at the result of a query. Using the EXPLAIN statement, you will get lots of useful info on the result produced by a specific query, as shown in the example below:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM ref_table,other_table WHERE ref_table.key_column=other_table.column;
```

**Don’t select what you don’t need**

A very common way to get the desired data is to use the * symbol, which will get all fields from the desired table:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts;
```

Instead, you should definitely select only the desired fields as shown in the example below. On a very small site with, let’s say, one visitor per minute, that wouldn’t make a difference. But on a site such as Cats Who Code, it saves a lot of work for the database.

```
SELECT title, excerpt, author FROM wp_posts;
```

**Avoid queries in loops**

When using SQL along with a programming language such as PHP, it can be tempting to use SQL queries inside a loop. But doing so is like hammering your database with queries.
This example illustrates the whole “queries in loops” problem:

```
foreach ($display_order as $id => $ordinal) {
    $sql = "UPDATE categories SET display_order = $ordinal WHERE id = $id";
    mysql_query($sql);
}
Here is what you should do instead:
UPDATE categories
    SET display_order = CASE id
        WHEN 1 THEN 3
        WHEN 2 THEN 4
        WHEN 3 THEN 5
    END
WHERE id IN (1,2,3)
```

**Use join instead of subqueries**

As a programmer, subqueries are something that you can be tempted to use and abuse. Subqueries, as show below, can be very useful:

```
SELECT a.id,
    (SELECT MAX(created)
    FROM posts
    WHERE author_id = a.id)
AS latest_post FROM authors a
```

Although subqueries are useful, they often can be replaced by a join, which is definitely faster to execute.

```
SELECT a.id, MAX(p.created) AS latest_post
FROM authors a
INNER JOIN posts p
    ON (a.id = p.author_id)
GROUP BY a.id
```

Source: http://20bits.com/articles/10-tips-for-optimizing-mysql-queries-that-dont-suck/